# I would like to do printFrequency method in java

Tags: java

I would like to create a method called `printFrequency` that adds up, and prints, the total number of occurrences of each possible value (0, 1, ..., 9) for my code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Array {

    int[] array;
    int size = 0;

    public Array(int s) {
        size = s;
        array = new int[size];
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.printf("%d,", array[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void fill() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(10);

    }

    public void sort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int tmp = array[i];
            int j = i;

            for (; j > 0 && (tmp < array[j - 1]); j--)
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    public void printFrequency() {

    }
}
```

I would like the output for the `printFrequency` method to be like this:

```
Frequencies:
There are 2, 0's
There are 0, 1's
There are 0, 2's
There are 0, 3's
There are 3, 4's
There are 0, 5's
There are 2, 6's
There are 1, 7's
There are 0, 8's
There are 2, 9's
```

I don't know exactly how to start with it and what loop to use for it or if there is easier way to do it.

Comment: Don't name your class as `Array`. Using existing class names from API, reduces readability and might create problem when you actually import an `Array` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to create a method called printFrequency that adds up, and prints, the total number of occurrences of each possible value (0, 1, ..., 9)

Assuming that you want to calculate the frequencies of the number present in the `array`, here is one solution using a fixed length array which acts as a count bucket for each of the numbers through 0 - 9.

Here is the code snippet:

```
private static void printFrequency() {
    int[] countArray = new int[10];
    for(int x : array) {
        countArray[x]++;
    }

    System.out.print("Frequencies: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("There are " + countArray[i] + ", " + i + "'s ");
    }
}
```